# Invalid parameter name binding oracle UDT

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net, user-defined-types

I am trying to use UDT in my code using ODP.NET. I have seen few examples but still when i run my code i get an error saying **Invalid parameter name binding**. Not able to find out where the code is failing. Please find below the code.

**Oracle Part:**

```
    create or replace 
TYPE T_SALES_PATTERN is object (siteID   varchar2(10),
 tankID   varchar2(10),
 dayNo     integer, 
 periodID  integer,
 startTime varchar2(4),
 endTime   varchar2(4),
 intraDayPctRate number(3,2),
 totalDailySalesPctRate number(3,2),
 averageDailySales integer,
 ouID varchar2(3)); 

create or replace 
TYPE T_SALES_PATTERN_TABLE is table of T_SALES_PATTERN;

function insertVMIFESalesPatterns( p_vmifeSalesPatterns T_SALES_PATTERN_TABLE) return integer is
begin
for recs in (select * from TABLE(p_vmifeSalesPatterns))
loop
  dbms_output.put_line(recs.siteID);
end loop;

  commit;
return g_SUCCESS;

exception when others then
  return g_ERROR;
end;
```

**C# Code:
Sales Pattern class**

```
public class SalesPattern : INullable, IOracleCustomType
    {
        private bool objectIsNull;

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("SITE_ID")]
        public string SiteId { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("TANK_ID")]
        public string TankId { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("DAYNO")]
        public long? DayNo { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("PERIODID")]
        public long? PeriodId { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("STARTTIME")]
        public string StartTime { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ENDTIME")]
        public string EndTime { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("INTRADAYPCTRATE")]
        public decimal? IntraDayPctRate { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("TOTALDAILYSALESPCTRATE")]
        public decimal? TotalDailySalesPctRate { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("AVERAGEDAILYSALES")]
        public long? AverageDailysales { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("OU_ID")]
        public string OuId { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("LASTUPDATETIMESTAMP")]
        public DateTime LastUpdateTimeStamp { get; set; }


        public static SalesPattern Null
        {
            get
            {
                SalesPattern salesPattern = new SalesPattern();
                salesPattern.objectIsNull = true;
                return salesPattern;
            }
        }

        #region INullable Members

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return objectIsNull; }
        }

        public void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            // Convert from the Custom Type to Oracle Object
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteId))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "SITE_ID", SiteId);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TankId))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "TANK_ID", TankId);
            }
            if (DayNo != null)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "DAYNO", DayNo);
            }
            if (PeriodId != null)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PERIODID", PeriodId);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StartTime))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "STARTTIME", StartTime);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EndTime))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ENDTIME", EndTime);
            }
            if (IntraDayPctRate != null)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "INTRADAYPCTRATE", IntraDayPctRate);
            }
            if (TotalDailySalesPctRate != null)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "TOTALDAILYSALESPCTRATE", TotalDailySalesPctRate);
            }
            if (AverageDailysales != null)
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "AVERAGEDAILYSALES", AverageDailysales);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OuId))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "OU_ID", OuId);
            }

        }

        public void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            SiteId = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "SITE_ID");
            TankId = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "TANK_ID");
            DayNo = (long)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "DAYNO");
            PeriodId = (long)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PERIODID");
            StartTime = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "STARTTIME");
            EndTime = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ENDTIME");
            IntraDayPctRate = (decimal)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "INTRADAYPCTRATE");
            TotalDailySalesPctRate = (decimal)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "TOTALDAILYSALESPCTRATE");
            AverageDailysales = (long)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "AVERAGEDAILYSALES");
            OuId = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "OU_ID");
        }

        #endregion

    }

    [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("T_SALES_PATTERN")]
    public class SalesPatternFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
    {
        #region IOracleCustomTypeFactory Members

        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new SalesPattern();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    /* SalesPatternList Class
   **   An instance of a SalesPatternList class represents an SalesPatternList object
   **   A custom type must implement INullable and IOracleCustomType interfaces
   */
    public class SalesPatternList : INullable, IOracleCustomType
    {
        [OracleArrayMapping()]
        public SalesPattern[] SalesPatternArray;

        private bool objectIsNull;

        #region INullable Members

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return objectIsNull; }
        }

        public static SalesPatternList Null
        {
            get
            {
                SalesPatternList obj = new SalesPatternList();
                obj.objectIsNull = true;
                return obj;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IOracleCustomType Members

        public void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, 0, SalesPatternArray);
        }

        public void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            SalesPatternArray = (SalesPattern[])OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, 0);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    [OracleCustomTypeMapping("T_SALES_PATTERN_TABLE")]
    public class SalesPatternListFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
    {
        #region IOracleCustomTypeFactory Members
        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new SalesPatternList();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IOracleArrayTypeFactory Members
        public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
        {
            return new SalesPattern[numElems];
        }

        public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
        {
            return null;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**ODP.NET Code:**

```
public long InsertSalesPattern(List<SalesPattern> salesList)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.Info("Entering insert VMI Sales Pattern method");
                SalesPatternList salesPatternList = new SalesPatternList();
                salesPatternList.SalesPatternArray = salesList.ToArray();

                using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connection))
                {
                    cmd = new OracleCommand("X4_DOM.insertVMIFESalesPatterns");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value", OracleDbType.Int16, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

                    OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "p_vmifeSalesPatterns";
                    parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
                    parameter.UdtTypeName = "T_SALES_PATTERN_TABLE";
                    parameter.Value = salesPatternList;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string result = cmd.Parameters["Return_Value"].Value.ToString();
                    logger.Info("VMI Sales Pattern");
                    return result == "0" ? 0 : 1;
                }
            }
            catch (OracleException e)
            {
                logger.Error("The Following error has occured: -" + e.Message);
                return -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("The Following error has occured: -" + ex.Message);
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm `siteID   varchar2(10)` vs `OracleObjectMappingAttribute("SITE_ID")]`. Is that right? Same question regarding `tankID` and `ouID`.

Comment: I think you may be right. The underscore probably should not be there in those three.

Comment: Even after removing the underscore the error is still the same. "Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: p_vmifeSalesPatterns"